# JQuery background video does not cover whole the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [Vide](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide#readme) to play a video in the background.
Here is the playing div tag.

```
<div style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"
  data-vide-bg="path/to/video" data-vide-options="loop: false, muted: false, position: 0% 0%">
</div>
```

when i change the style to

```
width: 100%; height: 100%;
```

The video disappears from the page. I want that video covers all page and I can scroll down.

Why does it happen?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Body background example</title>
<style>
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body data-vide-bg="video/ocean">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
 <script src="../src/jquery.vide.js"></script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

This is fine just put scroll bar or use some jquery for scroll purpose.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to cover all with the div and adjusted depending on the size of the screen, this is the code (Important, this is directive to the div):

```
style="
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-image: none; 
    background-position: 50% 50%; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;"
```

if you want in the body, in the folder examples/body-bg.html is the examples for apply to the body only: https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong units of measurement. If you pull the image in via CSS image-background then you can set the image-background-size to the contain property. It will insure that the video completely fits into it container (body, div, span, etc.).

```
body{
background-image:url(''your-video.mp4');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
image-background-size: contain;
}
```

Source: [w3schools CSS3 background-size Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

You could also try using the height and width but use the vh and vw metrics. It sets the height and width based on the view ports dimensions.

Source: [CSS Units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)